# Product Archive in WooCommerce 3.2.6 (Wordpress 4.8.5) shows 1 product description

Tags: wordpress

I was having problems with the Woocommerce products archive page (instead of displaying products, it displayed one product's description.  I solved that when, just after posting here, I simply created a new shop page.

I would, however, really prefer to use the correct page from the Woocommerce tools, so the Dashboard link to Visit Store works.

I thought shortcodes would be the answer...they are for a new page named Shop, but not for the Woocommerce page.  Does anyone here know what would cause this error, and how to fix it?

Thanks,
   --jim

[Original question edited//replaced by this new one]

Comment: Is reinstalling WooCommerce a viable option for you?

Comment: It's definitely not a good option, unless re-installing keeps my existing setup, products, etc.  That would be a MUCH worse inconvenience than having to remember to use Visit Site and from there Shop.  Support at my hosting site said they have no idea if even can edit the "Visit Store" link in the dashboard...that would fix everything.

Comment: You should try to clear WP's cache. Many plugins do that, like WP Super Cache. If that doesn't work there are a number of plugins online to backup your store and the importing it back after you change something. However, I don't think reinstalling WooCommerce should mess with your store setup. Also, you could try to change the permalink of the page you just created (your custom shop page) to *your_domain*/shop/. That might do it. Just click the **Edit** button below your page (in the admin area) and modify the permalink.

Comment: I did, in fact, just create a new page called "shop" using the shortcode [products].  That's working, but not for the "Visit Shop" link in the Dashboard.  It insists on going to the Woocommerce page, even if it no longer exists (resulting, obviously, in an error).  Right now, I'm just happy to have the shop page working for any customers that may find my site (it's WAY too soon to expect much, but then, you never know...  :-)

Comment: I did, in fact, just create a new page called "shop" using the shortcode [products].  That's working, but not for the "Visit Shop" link in the Dashboard.  It insists on going to the WC page, even if it no longer exists.  I set its permalink to broken-shop-page or something like that.  Even after I completely removed that one from the cache and deleted it, "Visit Store" insisted on trying to use it.  At this point, though, as I mentioned, I'm glad at least that it's good for any potential customers.  Thanks.

Comment: It's great that its working, but for the "Visit Shop" link I meant for you to change the new "shop" page's permalink to <<your_domain>>**/shop/**. Or just check what link is the "Visit Shop" following and change it to that. I don't know if I'm explaining myself well, in any case just tell me, but it shouldn't be difficult, I don't think it's a huge problem, and the best part is that you got it to work for the customers.

Comment: Like I said, I did change the new shop page's link to my doman + shop....  The Visit Shop "button" points to whatever the wooCommerce "shop" page is set to, even that page has been deleted...it still tries to go to that dead link instead of my newly-created "shop" page with a stub of "shop".      What I did to get it to work for customers is create a custom menu item that points to my page, instead of Woocommerce's page.  That's what I was saying in my previous response.